# Counting Sign Bit in 2's Complement in Memory Address

Tags: c++, memory-management, twos-complement

In c++, if memory address of a variable is displayed as 0XFFF, for instance, I am not sure if it's 2047 or 4095(including the "sign bit"). 0xFFF is 1111 1111 1111 in binary. And I have recently learned about the "sign bit", which just indicates if the number is positive or negative. My another guess is that it would be 0000 0000 0001 after converting into 2's complement positive number.
So my question is this: does memory address of 0XFFF indicate that it's 4095 or 2047? or, perhaps, is it 1?

Comment: 2's complement does **not** have a sign bit. That's 1's complement. In 2's complement, the Most Significant Bit has the opposite of its usual value. That's how 0xFFF = -2048 + 2047 ends up as -1, not -0.

Answer (score 0):

`0xFFF` can be *either*.  In hex, it's just bits - the rest is all in how you interpret it. It also depends on the width of the data type we're talking about.

Assuming you're not using a 12-bit datatype, the particular value you've shown is *always* 4095.

Now if we establish the width of our integer, and choose a different value, things get more interesting.  Take a 16-bit value 0xFFFF, for example:

- Interpretted As an *unsigned* integer (i.e. `uint16_t`), it is 65535.
- As a *signed* integer (i.e. `int16_t`), it is -1.

Comment: "24 bit datatype". That would be 12 bit adjusted for inflation.

Comment: @n.m. I can only imagine how my train of thought ended up at 24 bits. "4095 is the max value of a 12-bit DAC. DAC's are used in audio. Audio uses DSP. Some DSPs have 24-bit registers. Yes, 24-bits it is!"

Comment: If I assign unsigned/signed int to 0xFFFF, they both turn out to be 65,535. But if I assign int to 0xFFFFFFFF, it becomes -1. Is it because int is 4 bytes? It seems like binary numbers have to be 4 bytes as well for integers to get what I intend to get.

Comment: It's all in your variable declarations, and how you print it. You haven't shown either of those things. I can't help you without seeing your code. Please edit your original question to show what exactly you're seeing (your code and the output).

Answer (score 0):

Memory addresses are typically considered as unsigned values, so two's complement really doesn't come into play in this respect.

For signed C++ primitive types, the standard doesn't care. Whether it's stored as two's complement or not is determined by the CPU architecture, which for x86 and most architectures two's complement is used due to the ease of hardware implementation.